# Is "grounds" (as in a chunk of land) singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Am I correct that *grounds*, although sounding plural, is actually singular?

More specifically, which is better:

> I view Fedora as a testing grounds for new ideas.

or

> I view Fedora as testing grounds for new ideas.

Comment: vew → view? ---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the definition to which you refer, it is almost exclusively used to denote a tract or area of land given over to a specific purpose, or the area surrounding and belonging to a building or event, and in such cases *grounds* is used rather than *ground*. It is not exactly singular as it conjugates as any other standard plural. *Grounds* can however refer to a single specific tract or domain.

In your specific example you could use either the singular *ground* or the plural *grounds*, but if you use the latter then you should conjugate appropriately and omit the indefinite article *a*.

I believe the singular *testing ground* would be more appropriate as you are referring specifically to the environment in which you test (rather like referring to the type of soil in which you might plant a tree) as opposed to the domain in which you test (like referring to the gardens in which the tree is planted.)

Answer (score 4):

"Grounds", as in the area of land attached to an institution, is plural

"Testing ground" is more common than "Testing grounds", and is singular.

Answer (score 1):

"Grounds" is a plural covering various details unimportant to outsiders: *The grounds cover six acres and include a croquet lawn and a rose garden*.  Similarly,*The testing grounds outside Warminster include a mortar range and an engineer recovery area*.  But "testing ground" is not uncommon, particularly for an area where various things can be put through *the same* tests.  It sounds as if this is what you have in mind.